# Reading from a stream not knowing how much to expect [c#]

Tags: c#, arrays, stream

How can I read from a stream when I don't know in advance how much data will come in? Right now I just picked a number on a high side (as in code below), but there's no guarantee I won't get more than that.

So I read a byte at a time in a loop, resizing array each time? Sounds like too much resizing to be done :-/

```
TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
tcpclnt.Connect(ip, port);

Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

stm.Write(cmdBuffer, 0, cmdBuffer.Length);

byte[] response = new Byte[2048];
int read = stm.Read(response, 0, 2048);

tcpclnt.Close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting it all together, assuming you're not getting a HUGE (more than can fit into memory)amount of data:

```
TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
tcpclnt.Connect(ip, port);
Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();
stm.Write(cmdBuffer, 0, cmdBuffer.Length);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
byte[] buffer = new Byte[2048];
int length;
while ((length = stm.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    ms.Write(buffer, 0, length);
tcpclnt.Close();
byte[] response = ms.ToArray();
```

As mentioned the  `MemoryStream` will handle the dynamic byte array allocation for you. And `Stream.Read(byte[], int, int)` will return the length of the bytes found in this 'read' or `0` if it's reached the end.

Comment: thanks!! before I read responses I had something like this with array resizing, buffer copying.. only a couple more lines, but this is so much better

Answer (score 6):

MemoryStream is your friend

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream
```

Construct with no default size and it will autoresize.  Then just loop as you suggest reading a reasonable amount of data each time. I usually pick at minimum the MTU as the default buffer size.

To get the underlying byte[] array that it creates call

```
memoryStreamInstance.GetBuffer()
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the StreamReader class?  I'm not sure if it's applicable to this case, but I've used the StreamReader for reading HttpWebResponse response streams in the past.  Very easy to use.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stm);
String result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int count;
while ( (count = stm.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0 ) {
   // process buffer[0..count-1]
   // sample:
   // memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int amt = 0;
while((amt = stm.Read(buffer, 0, 1024) != 0)
{
   // do something
}
```

depends a bit on what you are receving, if just plain text you could store it in a stringbuilder, if large amounts of binary data, store it in say a memorystream

Comment: Fixed.  Shame I can't leave comment under 15 characters, I said everything I needed by char 7.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on what you are going to do with the data?

If you don't need it all at once you could just perform the read operation inside a loop?